# Cut() error - 'breaks' are not unique

Tags: r

I have following dataframe:

```
 a         
    ID   a.1    b.1     a.2   b.2
1    1  40.00   100.00  NA    88.89
2    2  100.00  100.00  100   100.00
3    3  50.00   100.00  75    100.00
4    4  66.67   59.38   NA    59.38
5    5  37.50   100.00  NA    100.00
6    6  100.00  100.00  100   100.00
```

When I apply the following code to this dataframe:

```
 temp <- do.call(rbind,strsplit(names(df)[-1],".",fixed=TRUE))
 dup.temp <- temp[duplicated(temp[,1]),]

 res <- lapply(dup.temp[,1],function(i) {
 breaks <- c(-Inf,quantile(a[,paste(i,1,sep=".")], na.rm=T),Inf)
 cut(a[,paste(i,2,sep=".")],breaks)
 })
```

the cut () function gives an error:

```
 Error in cut.default(a[, paste(i, 2, sep = ".")], breaks) : 
 'breaks' are not unique
```

However, the same code works perfectly well on similar dataframe:

```
 varnames<-c("ID", "a.1", "b.1", "c.1", "a.2", "b.2", "c.2")

 a <-matrix (c(1,2,3,4, 5, 6, 7), 2,7)

 colnames (a)<-varnames

 df<-as.data.frame (a)


    ID  a.1  b.1  c.1  a.2  b.2  c.2
  1  1    3    5    7    2    4    6
  2  2    4    6    1    3    5    7

 res <- lapply(dup.temp[,1],function(i) {
 breaks <- c(-Inf,quantile(a[,paste(i,1,sep=".")], na.rm=T),Inf)
 cut(a[,paste(i,2,sep=".")],breaks)
 })

 res
[[1]]
[1] (-Inf,3] (-Inf,3]
Levels: (-Inf,3] (3,3.25] (3.25,3.5] (3.5,3.75] (3.75,4] (4, Inf]

[[2]]
[1] (-Inf,5] (-Inf,5]
Levels: (-Inf,5] (5,5.25] (5.25,5.5] (5.5,5.75] (5.75,6] (6, Inf]

[[3]]
[1] (5.5,7] (5.5,7]
Levels: (-Inf,1] (1,2.5] (2.5,4] (4,5.5] (5.5,7] (7, Inf]
```

What it the reason for this error? 
How can it be fixed? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You get this error because quantile values in your data for columns `b.1`, `a.2` and `b.2` are the same for some levels, so they can't be directly used as breaks values in function `cut()`.

```
apply(a,2,quantile,na.rm=T)
       ID      a.1    b.1   a.2      b.2
0%   1.00  37.5000  59.38  75.0  59.3800
25%  2.25  42.5000 100.00  87.5  91.6675
50%  3.50  58.3350 100.00 100.0 100.0000
75%  4.75  91.6675 100.00 100.0 100.0000
100% 6.00 100.0000 100.00 100.0 100.0000
```

One way to solve this problem would be to put `quantile()` inside `unique()` function - so you will remove all quantile values that are not unique. This of course will make less breaking points if quantiles are not unique.

```
res <- lapply(dup.temp[,1],function(i) {
  breaks <- c(-Inf,unique(quantile(a[,paste(i,1,sep=".")], na.rm=T)),Inf)
  cut(a[,paste(i,2,sep=".")],breaks)
})

[[1]]
[1] <NA>        (91.7,100]  (58.3,91.7] <NA>        <NA>        (91.7,100] 
Levels: (-Inf,37.5] (37.5,42.5] (42.5,58.3] (58.3,91.7] (91.7,100] (100, Inf]

[[2]]
[1] (59.4,100]  (59.4,100]  (59.4,100]  (-Inf,59.4] (59.4,100]  (59.4,100] 
Levels: (-Inf,59.4] (59.4,100] (100, Inf]
```

Answer (score 22):

If you'd rather keep the number of quantiles, another option is to just add a little bit of jitter, e.g.

```
breaks = c(-Inf,quantile(a[,paste(i,1,sep=".")], na.rm=T),Inf)
breaks = breaks + seq_along(breaks) * .Machine$double.eps
```

Answer (score 15):

This comes from the fact that your breaks are not unique. Instead of `cut`, you should use `.bincode`, which accepts a non unique vector of breaks.

```
x <- c(0, 0.01, 0.5, 0.99, 1)
breaks <- c(0, 0, 1, 1)
.bincode(x, breaks)
```

Answer (score 9):

If you actually mean the 10% or 25% portions of your population when you say decile, quartile etc. and not the actual numeric values of the decile/quartile buckets, you can rank your values first, and apply the `quantile` function on the ranks:

```
a <- c(1,1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,7,7,7,99,0.5,100,54,3,100,100,100,11,11,12,11,0)
a_ranks <- rank(a, ties.method = "first")
decile <- cut(a_ranks, quantile(a_ranks, probs=0:10/10), include.lowest=TRUE, labels=FALSE)
```