# R: Vioplot gives cut() error

Tags: r

I'm attempting to use vioplot to generate plots for several columns from two different groups that I want to compare:

```
for (i in 19:length(data) ) {
    # violin plot
    vioplot(data[[1]][[i]], data[[2]][[i]], col="grey", names=names(data),     colMed="Green")
    # Calculate means
    means <- tapply(data[[i]], data[["category"]], mean)
    # Plot mean points.
    points(means, col="red", pch=16)
    # legend for median and mean in topright corner of plot.
    legend('topright', c("median","mean"), pch=16, col=c("green","red"))
}
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Error in cut.default(x, breaks = breaks) : 'breaks' are not unique
Calls: vioplot ... sm.density -> binning -> binning.1d -> cut -> cut.default
```

I think it may have something to do with quantiles being equal for some of the data columns as described here:
[Cut() error - 'breaks' are not unique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16184947/cut-error-breaks-are-not-unique)

Is there a way to make vioplot ignore these cases or force a plot anyway?

Thanks!

Comment: It's going to be hard without a reproducible example. Can you provide something we can use?

Comment: Are you just asking how to skip generating a graph in a loop when there's an error?

Comment: It looks like it fails for columns that are all zeros, in which case the quantiles are all zero.  I'm looking at tryCatch to continue the for loop rather than break with an error.