# Ranking 200000 rows in 1:10 groups with r

Tags: r, ranking

I have a data set that has 200,00 rows what I want to do is simple, but I haven't found an answer to how.  I tried this:

```
    data$DCRank<-cut(data$DC,quantile(data$DC,(0:10)/10),include.lowest=TRUE)
```

But that doesn't give me a 1:10 result.

Comment: I get an error:   data$DCRank<-cut(data$DC=(1:200)%%10+1, breaks=0:10, labels=0:9)
Error: unexpected '=' in "data$DCRank<-cut(data$DC=

Comment: Try this: `breaks <- quantile(data$DC,probs=(seq(0,1,0.1))) ;
cut(data$DC, breaks=breaks)`

Comment: So a couple things I need to keep it in the same dataframe as a new column,  and that is still giving me a result that is not a 1:10 result.  I can do this in excel, but with a data set this big the time to calc is no good.

Comment: You can add labels, and store them as a new column in your `data` data frame: `breaks <- quantile(data$DC,probs=(seq(0,1,0.1))) ;
data$DCrank <- cut(data$DC, breaks=breaks, labels=0:9)`

Comment: That works...  Mostly.  It gives 0 an na rank

Comment: To take care of 0, you should add `include.lowest=T` in the `cut` statement

Comment: AWESOME!! thank you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100610/discussion-between-ally-kat-and-ram-narasimhan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
DCbreaks <- quantile(data$DC,probs=(seq(0,1,0.1))) 
data$DCrank <- cut(data$DC, breaks=DCbreaks, labels=0:9+1, include.lowest=TRUE)
```

Comment: This works most of the time however on some of my data sets I get this error    ;  Error in cut.default(data$Trades, breaks = breaks, labels = 0:9, include.lowest = T) : 
  'breaks' are not unique

Comment: This is happening because some of your quantiles are the same. You need to make them unique. Try the suggestion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16184947/cut-error-breaks-are-not-unique